# Drawing triangle on the console

Tags: java, triangle

I have been trying to draw triangle by specific coordinates on java. I kinda drew it but there is a problem. I put the output and my code down there. As you can see, sides of the triangle are too long, I need to limit them. Can you guys help me out with this, maybe give me some idea?

[image]

```
System.out.print("For triangle, we need the coordinates of the points for three vertices. \nPlease enter the coordinates of 3 vertices a, b, c, d, e, f:-5 2 0 6 5 2 \n");
        

a=input.nextInt();

int b=input.nextInt();

int c=input.nextInt();
int d=input.nextInt();
int e=input.nextInt();
int f=input.nextInt();
for (int y = 10; y >= -11; y--) {
    for (int x = -10; x <= 11; x++) {
    
    if(y==0) {              
        if(((x-c)*(d-b)/(c-a)+d==0)||((x-e)*(f-d)/(e-c)+f==0)||(x-a)*(b-f)/(a-e)+b==0)  
            System.out.print("*");   
            else if(x==0)
                System.out.print("|");
            else if(x==11)
                System.out.print("x");
            else
                System.out.print("-");
        }
    else if(((x-c)*(d-b)/(c-a)+d==y)||((x-e)*(f-d)/(e-c)+f==y)||(x-a)*(b-f)/(a-e)+b==y)              
        System.out.print("*"); 
        else if(x==0) {
            if(y==10)
                System.out.print("y");
            else
                System.out.print("|");
        }
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");    
}
```

Comment: what are `a b c d e f` variables for and what are their values?

Comment: You are aware of how integer arithmetic works, yes?  Truncation and such

Comment: @RisingSun (a,b) (c,d) (e,f) these are the coordinates of vertices. In this example, they are (-5,3) (0,6) (5,3)

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, i guess.

Comment: You just need another check to see if the current coordinates are within those vertices and only print if so